# Golf competition

Tags: gambling

There is a one hole golf competition played by 1000 people, entry is 1 dollar.

Contestants play a par 3 once, and if they get a hole-in-one, they win. If multiple people get a hole-in-one, the jackpot is shared between them. If no one gets a hole in one, the house takes the money.

Everyone has an equal chance of getting a hole-in-one,$\dfrac{1}{100}$.

The question is, what are the expected returns for a player in this competition?

I tried this using an exhaustive tree diagram/spreadsheet, but it got very tedious.Anyone know a nice way to do this?

Comment: $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{N}{n} \left({N \atop n}\right) p^n (1 - p)^{N - n}$
where
$p = 1/100$
and $N = 1000$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I had to think about that for a while. Thanks so much, very insightful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chance that *nobody* will hit a hole in one is 
$$
\left( \frac{99}{100} \right)^{1000} \approx 0.000043
$$
This makes the total expected house take $0.043$.

So since everybody will have an equal expectations, the expected return for any given player is
$$
1- \left( \frac{99}{100} \right)^{1000} \approx 0.999957
$$

Comment: Less the entry fee.  $E[X] = -(\frac {99}{100})^{999}$